# Set range from used range offset

Tags: excel, vba, range, cells

I would like to build a range to do work on.  I am able to return the row and column indices of last used cell but how do I include this in a named range?

```
numRows = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
numColumns = sht.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set endRange = sht.Cells(numRows, numColumns)

Set workRange = sht.Range("B1", Cells(numRows, numColumns)?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
With sht
    numRows = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    numColumns = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Set endRange = .Cells(numRows, numColumns)

    Set workRange = .Range("B1", endRange)

    .Parent.Names.Add Name:="myName", RefersToR1C1:=workRange.Address
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Set workRange = sht.Range("B1", Cells(numRows, numColumns))
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="myName", RefersToR1C1:=workRange.Address
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set rng = .Range("B1:" & .Cells(numRows, numColumns).Address)
        ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="workRange", RefersTo:=rng
End With
```

Note that you can run this any number of times and it will simply overwrite the existing named variable "workRange" without any problems.

To build it up as a series of non-contiguous ranges you simply use the above but append the additional ranges on to the string with commas like this:

```
Set rng=.Range("B1:C2,E4:F6,G2:" & Cells(numRows,numColumns).Address)
```